# WSO2 Auth off Facebook and Windows live

Tags: facebook, wso2, live

I've been doing some reading up on wso2. I've installed the Identity server and hit a bit of a brick wall.

I'm trying to allow users to auth via facebook and windows live. I assume i will be using oauth to do this. However, i just cant seem to figure out how or where i do this.

Could someone please just direct me in the right direction.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to use oauth option. WSO2 IS 5 supports for many third party login providers. You need to create app on Oauth on provider & configure accordingly with IS.

here is a good example how to use facebook login via WSO2 IS.

http://prasadtissera.blogspot.com/2014/04/login-with-facebook-for-wso2-identity.html

Good luck

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you perhaps know how to use php to now auth off this setup? Perhaps so documentation on it?