# WSO2 API Client auth (facebook)

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Im really just looking for some guidance here.

My goal is to create (for instance) a webpage, client will then  enter there authentication details on that site, which will talk to the wso2 Identity server, which in turn will talk to either facebook, or some oauth provider and authenticate the user. The user will then be allowed to use that site.

What im looking for is the url for the wsdl. I've read quite abit an notice alot of people talking about the wso2 API Manager. Do i need to install that?

Thank you in advance.

p.s: I asked a similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446585/wso2-auth-off-facebook-and-windows-live). The answer got me pretty far, however using soapUI on the RemoteUserStoreManagerService wsdl, i am unable to auth facebook users. Also i will be using php to write this website.

Comment: WSO2 API manager uses tbuo expose APIs to external parties, Authentication provider is WSO2IS. you didn't want to have API manager for this.

Comment: @Dakshia ok cool thanks. You dont perhaps have an example of a "login with Facebook" for php and wso2